# insert text in the joomla editor

Tags: joomla

I'm creating a component for Joomla.
In the backend I added an editor like this:

```
$editor = JFactory::getEditor();
$editor->display('codice', 'test', '100%', '768', '40', '5',false);
```

I added the buttons.
Clicking these buttons I would like to enter text for example: [code]test[code]
at the point where the user was writing.
how do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Replace button and editor id as per your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#button" ).click(function() { 
     $("#txteditorid").text("[code]test[code]");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I just found this js function: jInsertEditorText